# QProgressBar problem with uploading

Tags: c++, qt, upload, progress-bar

I show my code first, then I explain my problem:

```
...
// somewhere in the constructor
    progressBar = new QProgressBar(this);
    progressBar->setMinimum(0);
    progressBar->setMaximum(100);
...
    connect(&http, SIGNAL(dataSendProgress(int, int)), this, SLOT(updateProgressBar(int, int)));
...
void MainWindow::updateProgressBar(int bytesSent, int total)
{
        progressBar->setMaximum(total);
        progressBar->setValue(bytesSent);
}
```

So this is how I try to make my progressBar being updated when I upload a file. The problem is, it won't do the job. When it starts uploading, I set the value of the progress bar to 0, then (thanks to this slot) it won't actually show the progress, but will jump to 100% immediately (even before it finished uploading).

I already checked the HTTP Client example, and copied the progress bar part, it is for downloading, and more or less is the same as for uploading but it uses the dataReadProgress signal (needed for downloading) AND it `works` perfectly.
Does anybody know how to solve this for uploading?

Comment: Are you performing the upload in a separate thread?  If you are performing the upload in the GUI thread, the progress bar may not be updated since the thread is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using QHttp and not QNetworkAccessManager. QHttp is deprecated and has bugs related to the progress signals.

Please look into using http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.7-snapshot/qnetworkreply.html#downloadProgress and http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.7-snapshot/qnetworkreply.html#uploadProgress

Answer (score 0):

From the Qt Doc:

> Warning: done and total are not
>   necessarily the size in bytes, since
>   for large files these values might
>   need to be "scaled" to avoid overflow.
>
> See also dataReadProgress(), post(),
>   request(), and QProgressBar.

So in case `done` is (for example) in Bytes (say 10 B) and `total` in kBytes (say 7 kB) then  `total < done` and therefore the progressBar goes to 100%

Comment: actually I printed out both of the values when the signal was emitted, and the reason it jumped to 100% was that both of the values (done/total) were the same (like 13340/13340) at the beginning of the upload process already